# JSF: Validation error

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2

This has to be the most asked issue around JSF here, and I have found many resources but failed to fix it anyway.

So, the issue description is that I have a JSF page with selectOneMenu component, which is correctly populated with data when rendered. On the page submit I receive validation error, I suspect it is because the data in this component are already lost, but I am not sure how to keep them in there.

So, the relevant code snippets:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="user" value="#{taskController.user}" />
    <f:viewParam name="taskId" value="#{taskController.taskId}" />
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{taskController.queryTask}" /> 

<!--     <f:viewAction action="#{taskController.queryTask}" />-->

</f:metadata>

<ui:param name="pageTitle" value="Select service task" />

<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Select service task" />
          <h:panelGrid columns="2">
              <h:panelGroup>Task Id</h:panelGroup>
              <h:panelGroup>#{taskController.task.id}</h:panelGroup>
              <h:panelGroup>Created by</h:panelGroup>
              <h:panelGroup>#{taskController.task.taskData.createdBy.id}</h:panelGroup>
              <h:panelGroup>Task Status</h:panelGroup>
              <h:panelGroup>#{taskController.task.taskData.status}</h:panelGroup>



 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{taskController.selectedServiceUUID}">
        <f:selectItems id = "test" value="#{taskController.content.get('srampServiceList')}" var="service"
        itemLabel="#{service.name}" itemValue="#{service.UUID}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu> 


          </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton action="#{taskController.completeSelectServiceTask}" value="Select service" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

The selectedServiceUUID is always null hence the validation fails. As I said, the selectOneMenu component includes correct data (from taskController.content.get('srampServiceList')}) when it is loaded.

My controller has following annotations:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
@ViewScoped
@Model
public class TaskController
```

Method

```
taskController.completeSelectServiceTask
```

is never called because of the validation error

```
sourceId=j_idt10:j_idt25[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(j_idt10:j_idt25: Validation Error: Value is not valid), detail=(j_idt10:j_idt25: Validation Error: Value is not valid)]
```

for completeness, the body of queryTask (which sets required data)

```
public void queryTask() {

FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
if (!facesContext.isPostback() && !facesContext.isValidationFailed()) {


    String message;
    try {

        task = taskBean.getTask(taskId);
        content = taskBean.getContent();

        message = "Loaded task " + taskId + ".";

        logger.info(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Unable to query for task with id = " + taskId;
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, message, e);
        facesContext.getExternalContext().getFlash().put("msg", message);
    }

}
```

}

taskcontroller.selectedServiceUUID is of type String, service.UUID is String too.
Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: I noticed you added both `@Model` and `@ViewScoped` on `TaskController`, but `@Model` is `@RequestScoped` cdi bean as [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Model.html) states.

Comment: Whereas `@ViewScope` is a JSF bean.
You cannot mix this two bean facilities JSF and CDI, you have to choose one.

Comment: Right on. This is surely the root cause, however removing @Model annotation makes my application constantly fails - I will need to investigate this further. I have come up with a workaround using javascript (button which copies one specific value to the text input). I consider this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by landal79 the problem was using @Model annotation which is request scoped, as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Model.html). Replacing @Model with @ViewScoped && @ManagedBean fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please create id's for all elements. It would be usefull to debug this kind of problem :)

```
<h:commandButton value="Dodaj rekomendacje" id="addRecomendation" styleClass="btn">
 <f:ajax event="click" render="rederPanel" listener="#{customerWrapper.addRecomendationToClient()}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: I am not sure how that helps but okay, I have added IDs to those elements.   <h:form id = "selectServiceForm"> ////   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{taskController.selectedServiceUUID}" id="serviceMenu">.. So, now the error reflects this in following manner : summary=(selectServiceForm:serviceMenu: Validation Error: Value is not valid) .

Comment: Is it possible that picked value Is out of possible values. Plz try to set default value on bean. Maybe that might help. Oh one more thing. Is value type of string?

Comment: Hi, setting default value does not help - same exception occurs. It seems like when I hit submit button the queryTask method is invoked again - taskId is lost - it goes to default value 0. Therefore the getContent method will return empty content. Therefore the list of services will be null.  Hence the validation error. Though I know all the symptons I am still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can u try to change action to partial refresh like this in my answer. I think that data from view scope r removed and reloaded.